# How do I fix "Undefined variable" error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

Today, I have started to learn PHP. And, I have created my first PHP file to test different variables. You can see my file as follows.

```
<?php
    $x = 5; // Global scope

    function myTest()
    {
        $y = 10; // Local scope
        echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
        echo "Variable x is: $x";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Variable y is: $y";
    }

    myTest();

    echo "<p>Test variables outside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
?>
```

I have found the following errors when I have run this file in the browser.

> Notice: Undefined variable: x in /opt/lampp/htdocs/anand/php/index.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: y in /opt/lampp/htdocs/anand/php/index.php on line 29

How can I fix the issue regarding it?

Comment: You can make Global variable for this error . http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 13):

The first error (`$x` is undefined) is because globals are not imported into functions by default (as opposed to "super globals", which are).

You need to tell your function you're referencing the global variable `$x`:

```
function myTest()
{
  global $x; // $x refers to the global variable

  $y=10; // local scope
  echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
  echo "Variable x is: $x";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Variable y is: $y";
}
```

Otherwise, PHP cannot tell whether you are shadowing the global variable with a local variable of the same name.

The second error (`$y` is undefined), is because local scope is just that, local. The whole point of it is that `$y` doesn't "leak" out of the function. Of course you cannot access `$y` later in your code, outside the function in which it is defined. If you could, it would be no different than a global.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    $a = 1; /* Global scope */

    function test()
    {
        echo $a; /* Reference to local scope variable */
    }

    test();
?>
```

You are getting the first error because the variable $a can't access the global variable's value unless you explicitly declare `global $a` inside the function.

Example #1 Using a global

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;

    function Sum()
    {
        global $a, $b; // If you want to access a global variable,
                       // you have to use the 'global' keyword

        $b = $a + $b;
    }

    Sum();
    echo $b;
?>
```

And the last error you are getting because **$y** is defined inside the function `mytest()` so its scope will be limited to that function only.

For a detailed explanation, read *[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)*.

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases of using a variable **globally**:

1. Using a single copy of that variable and modify it from anywhere i.e. modification from within a function or outside i.e. in the global scope. In that case you need a declaration in the allowed set of function in the form **`global $x;`**.
2. In case you need local variables for individual functions with the **same identifier** used for the global variable (i.e. variables outside all functions); in that case you have two variables with the same name i.e. one local and one global for that function. Then you need to use a **superglobal** variable **`$GLOBALS`** i.e. an array of all the global variables. I personally prefer this approach to make efficient code;

The following are the code for the two.

### Code 1 (using global declaration)

```
<?php
    $x = 5; // Global scope

    function myTest()
    {
        $y = 10; // Local scope
        global $x;

        echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
        echo "Variable x in global scope is: $x";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Variable y is: $y";
    }

    myTest();

    echo "<p>Test variables outside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
?>
```

### Code 2 (using the $GLOBALS[] array)

```
<?php
    $x = 5; // Global scope

    function myTest()
    {
        $y = 10; // Local scope
        $x = 23;

        echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
        echo "Variable x in global scope is: " . $GLOBALS['x'];
        echo "<br>Variable x in local scope is: $x";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Variable y is: $y";
    }

    myTest();

    echo "<p>Test variables outside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
?>
```

For **[REFERENCE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)**.

Answer (score 2):

Set $x as a global, like

```
global $x;
```

Or try this:

```
<?php
    $x = 5; // Global scope

    function myTest($x)
    {
        $y=10; // Local scope
        echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
        echo "Variable x is: $x";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Variable y is: $y";
    }

    myTest($x);

    echo "<p>Test variables outside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is behaving as expected, but if you want to use both the variables across the script use this:

```
<?php
    $x = 5; // Global scope

    function myTest(){
        global $x;
        global $y;
        $y = 10;

        echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
        echo "Variable x is: $x";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Variable y is: $y";
    }
    myTest();

    echo "<p>Test variables outside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

```
function myTest()
{
    $y = 10; // Local scope
    global $x;
    .....
}
```

By declaring $x global within the function, it will refer to the global version of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn the scope of a variable in PHP. See *[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)*.

In your code, $x is a global one, so in order to access that variable inside the function use `global $x;` at the beginning of the function, that is,

```
function myTest()
{
    global $x;
    $y = 10; // Local scope

    echo "<p>Test variables inside the function:<p>";
    echo "Variable x is: $x";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Variable y is: $y";
}
```

For $y, either you skip that output by checking isset($y) or else assign a default value at the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

put $x outside the"" in code like echo" Variable $x is:".$x;